# Equation discrepancy ?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's a *(possibly dumb)* question I found

```
If sqrt(2x-1) = -x , find x
```

The way to solve it is essentially

```
Square both sides i.e. 2x-1 = x^2
 => x^2-2x+1 = 0
 => x(x-1)-1(x-1) = 0
 => (x-1)^2 = 0
 => x = 1
```

But subbing this back we get  `sqrt(2x-1) = 1 ! = -x i.e. -1`

Also if  `(x-1)^2 = 0 => x=+1 or x=-1` , even then it doesn't solve the problem at some point `(sqrt(2x-1) = sqrt(-3) ! = 1)`

Is the first question assumption itself wrong? If so how does it resolve to a solid answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lhs is defined for $x\geq1/2$; for those $x$ the lhs is non-negative whereas the rhs is negative.

Some explanation: squaring is “if” but not “iff”: if $x=5$ then $ x^2=25$, but if $x^2=25$ then $x$ may be $-5$ as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get that

Comment: The left side, $\sqrt{2x-1}$, is not defined when $x<1/2$, right, Slart? But when $x\ge1/2$, then the left side is at least zero, while the right side is less than zero, right? So the equation can't possibly have a solution. So any solution you may think you have found, will be "extraneous". OK?

Comment: Got it, a moment of dumbness came over me when I saw this answer. I found this question written on a whiteboard at a friend's workplace and saw it solved in the manner I did with a big question mark at the end which made me wonder lol.

Answer (score 0):

when you squared both sides, you generated an extraneous solution (two solutions instead of one)..
...I don't know where you received this problem, but is it possible this is a "trick" type problem? I mean, you could simply flip the sign on both sides...so 
-(sqrt(2x-1)) = x 
hope this helped a little...-

Comment: I found it written on a whiteboard at a friend's workplace and saw it solved with a big question mark at the end which made me wonder . :)  Thanks!

Comment: "two solutions instead of one" Actually, one solution instead of none.